# Looking for a Web-Frontend for a single SQL-Server table

Tags: web-apps, sql-server

we are using a FreePBX VOIP-System. We want to make a Phone-Protocol where each Call is shown and Users can add Information and assign the Call to an co-worker. 
The list will have some fields, which are prefilled by FreePBX (Phonenumber, Companyname, Date) but some must be filled out by the user (Assignee, Reason for the Call).

What I have achieved so far is that all Calls will be send to a SQL-Server Database.
Now I need a webfrontend, where users can see the list and update the list. Updating should be as easy as in excel. The users are endusers, therefore, using SQL statements to update is not possible.

I would prefer a solution for an Microsoft SQL Server (because the server is already setup) but if there is a better solution for e.g. mySQL I am interested to it as well.

Thank you!

PS: 
I tried MS Access but using SQL Server as linked Database does not allow updating the table.